# SQL store variable number of data and then select them by multiple elements

Tags: sqlite, database-design

Imagine I want to create a SQLite database of films, where the columns correspond to: title publication year, genre... How would you do it to store a list of actors in the database? Consider that:

- Since the number of actors may vary from film to film, I cannot use one column per actor.
- SQLite does not have a data type that corresponds to a list.
- I want to use, for example `"SELECT filmname FROM table WHERE X"`. Where X would be something that indicates if an actor is present in the film. I would like to be able to use a single or multiple actors on X

The best thing I though is to use a single string, like `"actor1_actor2"`, and then apply `"WHERE actorname LIKE %actor1"`. But that would allow me to filter films by only one actor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You create tables `movies`, `actors` and a separate bridge table `movies_actors` for defining your many-to-many relationship (movie<->actor). The simplest form of the bridge table includes two columns, such as `movie_id` and `actor_id`, and two foreign keys: `movies_actors.movie_id -> movies.id` and `movies_actors.actor_id -> actors.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, create a mapping separate table for the actress with a mapping key as Film's primary table. so that you can run all type of query operations on your table structure.

Comment: Could you give me some example or documentation? I have no idea about that.